# Countability of Collection of All Finite Subsets of a Countable Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

Let V be a countable set. Ok, first thing to say is that this isn't a question as to whether $S = \{ A \subseteq V \mid A \ \text{finite} \}$ is countable -- there are plenty of other duplicates on SE asking the same question! This question is regarding the legitimacy of a method that I've been thinking about. Wlog let $V$ be infinite, otherwise the result is trivial.

---

Fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider $S_n = \{ A \subseteq V \mid |S| = n\}$. ($S_0 = \emptyset$.)

- For $n = 1$, this is just the set of singletons of $V$, and so is countable.
- For $n = 2$, this is just the set of pairs of $V$, and so, by the "countable collection of countables is countable" argument, is countable.
- For general $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider $N \choose n$, which, for fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$, is a polynomial in $n$. Since we can iterate the "countable collection of countables is countable" argument, we have countability for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (That is to say, this follows since the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients of degree $n$ is countable.)

Now, further we know that the set of *all* polynomials with integer coefficients is countable. Letting $P_n$ be the set of polynomials (with integer coefficients -- assume this whenever talking about polynomials) of degree $n$, we have that the set of all polynomials $P = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P_n$. Similarly (in our above notation), $S = \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n$. From this can we then deduce that $S$ is countable?

My main concern is the following. If $|V| = N \in \mathbb{N}$ (so $V$ is finite), then $|S_n| = {N \choose n}$. Since the union is disjoint, we then have that
$$|S| = \sum_{n=1}^N {N \choose n} = 2^N.$$
But $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$. So if we just let $N \to \infty$ in the above equation, then naively we get $|S| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$, which says that $S$ is uncountable.

---

Alternatively, we can think of it another way (very similar). Without considering polynomials, we can just say that $S_n$ is countable for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we're summing/unioning over a countable set, and so the result follows from the "countable collection of countable is countable" argument.

---

Any comments on this would be most appreciated. The 'proof' (if it is a proof) does seem to be fine to me (I'm pretty sure the concern mentioned above is just that if you do the rigorous maths then you'll find that you can't just swap the limits naively). However, in the many SE questions asking if $S$ is countable, everyone (that I've seen) tries to set up some function that is an injection to deduce the result. This is fine, if you can come up with the injection, but my above method seems much more intuitive. (There is one that has a similar method, but they claim that $S_n$ is *finite* for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and that's (a place) where their proof fell down.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

1. It's unclear to me why the set of pairs is countable because of the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable. You might want to elaborate there.
2. It's not true that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$. That would be the continuum hypothesis which cannot be proved or disproved from the standard axioms of set theory.
3. Cardinal functions have no reason to be continuous. So arguing that something is uncountable just because $N\to\infty$ is a common mistake.
4. In general the statement that countable unions of countable sets are countable depends on the axiom of choice, whereas the statement you are trying to prove does not. There is nothing wrong in using the axiom of choice, but it's worth knowing when you're using it.
5. What's also unclear is that if you know that polynomials with integer coefficients are countable, why aren't you done already? I mean, every finite set defines a unique polynomial (just write the set in increasing order and those are the coefficients). So we're about done. The trick in these proofs is generally to avoid sets like that.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll reply with various points, which I'll separate into individual comments. (For some reason, I'm not doing them in any particular order... sorry about that...)

Comment: I had thought that (3) was the case. I'm not set-theorist, just this was something that I was thinking about in connection with a probability-theory topic; as such, I'm not massively comfortable with determining such things, so I thought I'd ask. :)

Comment: More interestingly is (2). I was unaware that this wasn't true. It is true, though, that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$, yeah? This follows by taking a bijection between the power set of the naturals and the real line. (I can't think of the exact bijection at the moment, but I'm sure I could come up with it if necessary; I would prove that both are uncountable using the same diagonal method, and I'd hope to be able to use this to set up some bijection.)

Comment: With regards to (1), is it not just that the set of pairs is $V \times V$, and this is countable for exactly the same reason that considering $\mathbb{Q}$ as (a subset of) $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. (So, in fact, I'm using "finite union of countable is countable".)

Comment: For (4), I didn't realise that I was using the axiom of choice (as I said, not a set-theorist!), so that is interesting to know. Is using this generally frowned upon, or is it fine *provided you are clear that you're using it*?

Comment: With (5), I did think that, as I said, since each set of size $n$ defines an $n-1$ dimensional polynomial, we should then be done. I was uneasy about this almost purely because I couldn't find any other reference that uses this method; all the other ones (that I found) found some injection into the naturals. This is fine *if you can come up with the function*, which takes practice to be able to think of them, whereas my method didn't really involve any ideas that are 'plucked out of the air'.

Comment: Let me condense my replies: (1) Now I'm really confused as to which countable sets you're taking the union of, and whether or not you ending up practically assuming that $S_n$ is countable to begin with, because that would be begging the question. (2) Yes, the cardinality of $\Bbb R$ is still $2^{\aleph_0}$, and you can find a bijection, but it's a bit ugly; just proving two sets are uncountable, however, does not make them equipotent. (4) It's fine, but it's always good to know when you appeal to choice, as it's non-constructive, and again you can prove this without choice. (5) in the next ..

Comment: .. comment: (5) it is often easy to prove that the finite sequences are countable by products of primes, and then prove there is an obvious surjection from finite sequences to finite subsets and therefore the finite subsets are countable; and it's sometimes very beneficial to actually construct the bijection witnessing the countability of the finite subsets by hand. I also like to use order theoretic proofs when I teach that subject. Generally, however, mathematics is not done in void, and even if ideas seem "plucked", they're rarely so. Most of the time you just don't know the origin of it.

Comment: Ok, I have made a *really* unhelpful typo. Note the corrected definition of of $S_n$, in particular the replacement of "$|S|$" by "$|A|$". When mentioning "pairs", I was talking about "pairs of elements of $V$", so $(v,v') \in V \times V$. With regards to (5) though, let me clarify. By "plucked out of the air", I mean "plucked out of the air to those who aren't familiar/comfortable with set theory". For example, I was chatting with my friend who does theoretical physics the other day, and he was saying that he didn't like introductory undergraduate analysis because lots of the stuff is...

Comment: "plucked out of the air", but I was arguing that, when you're unfamiliar with the topic, it does seem like the proofs/examples are unmotivated. However, the more you do and the more familiar you get, the more you understand how to do such proofs/examples. I'm 100% sure that this is **exactly** the same for set-theory! However, most people who post the question "Is the set of all finite subsets of \mathbb{N} countable?" aren't going to be that advanced (I wouldn't think), but will maybe be undergraduates or doing undergraduate material. As such, it likely seems unmotivated to them.

Comment: Anyway, we could go on indefinitely like that, but thank you very much for your comments; they have certainly helped. :)